# Compile Objective-C with ubuntu's makefile

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make a Makefile which would compile my Objective-C project in Linux (ubuntu 14.04 running on Koding).

The command I use in the bash to compile is:

gcc $(gnustep-config --objc-flags) main.m $(gnustep-config --base-libs) -o ./bin/main

So I tryied something simple like:

```
FLAGS=$(gnustep-config --objc-flags)
LIBS=$(gnustep-config --base-libs)

all:
    gcc $(FLAGS) main.m $(LIBS) -o ./bin/main
```

But when I run the makefile it says:

> gcc  main.m  -o ./bin/main main.m:1:34: fatal error:
>   Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory  #import
>   
>                                     ^ compilation terminated. make: *** [all] Error 1

Y also tryed to replace the vars FLAGS and LIBS with the consoles output of running the specific command, like:

```
FLAGS=-MMD -MP -DGNUSTEP -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_GUI_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_RUNTIME=1 -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fobjc-exceptions -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS -pthread -fPIC -Wall -DGSWARN -DGSDIAGNOSE -Wno-import -g -O2 -fgnu-runtime -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -fexec-charset=UTF-8 -I. -I/home/mjdegue/GNUstep/Library/Headers -I/usr/local/include/GNUstep -I/usr/include/GNUstep
```

But in that case I get an output like:

```
gcc -MMD -MP -DGNUSTEP -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_GUI_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_RUNTIME=1 -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -fno-stri
ct-aliasing -fexceptions -fobjc-exceptions -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS -pthread -fPIC -Wall -DGSWARN -DGSDIAGNOSE -Wno-i
mport -g -O2 -fgnu-runtime -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -fexec-charset=UTF-8 -I. -I/home/mjdegue/GNUstep/L
ibrary/Headers -I/usr/local/include/GNUstep -I/usr/include/GNUstep main.m -rdynamic -pthread -shared-libgcc -fexceptio
ns -fgnu-runtime -L/home/mjdegue/GNUstep/Library/Libraries -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lgnustep-base -lobjc -lm -o ./
bin/main
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-MMD -MP -DGNUSTEP -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_GUI_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_RU
NTIME=1 -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fobjc-exceptions -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS -pthrea
d -fPIC -Wall -DGSWARN -DGSDIAGNOSE -Wno-import -g -O2 -fgnu-runtime -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -fexec-c
harset=UTF-8 -I. -I/home/mjdegue/GNUstep/Library/Headers -I/usr/local/include/GNUstep -I/usr/include/GNUstep'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The question would be:

Is there anyway to make a reference to the variables $(gnustep-config --objc-flags) & $(gnustep-config --base-libs) being them contained in FLAGS / LIBS?

If not: How could I make this work?

Thanks a lot people.

Comment: Why don't you use gnustep make package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think variables are settable that way from shell output.

Try:

```
FLAGS = $(shell gnustep-config --objc-flags)
LIBS = $(shell gnustep-config --base-libs)

all:
    gcc $(FLAGS) main.m $(LIBS) -o ./bin/main
```

or, this syntax:

```
FLAGS = `gnustep-config --objc-flags`
LIBS = `gnustep-config --base-libs`

all:
    gcc $(FLAGS) main.m $(LIBS) -o ./bin/main
```

or, you could store the command, and execute them in place:

```
FLAGS = gnustep-config --objc-flags
LIBS = gnustep-config --base-libs

all:
    gcc `$(FLAGS)` main.m `$(LIBS)` -o ./bin/main
```

Comment: Great. I used the first way and it works perfectly. I have not tryed the others yet. Thanks a lot for helping!